# Accessing item in for loop through querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use addEventListener on each li in side a list obtained from querySelectorAll, changing each item color as I hover the mouse over it. However I cannot change color by using the index of the item in the list but have to use this. I wonder why index doesnt work here

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
   lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
       this.style.color = "green";
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use `mouseout` event. You can also use `classList.add` to add a class on `mouseover` & on `mouseout` use `classList.remove` which will remove the class

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.classList.add("green");
  });

  lis[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.classList.remove("green");
  });
}
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>



</ul>
```